# How to better handle populating my master-detail type page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

So I'm working on my first ASP.NET MVC 3 application and I've display a jqGrid to the user with the various Ice Creams we make.  Upon selecting one of the rows, I currently invoke `Url.Action("Details", "IceCream")` and that ends up creating an IceCreamDetails view model which has a bunch of lists (e.g., RelatedDesserts, HistoricData) and do something like so over in my Details.cshtml:

```
...

<div>
@foreach (var related in Model.RelatedDesserts)
{
   @Html.Partial("_RelatedDessert", related)
}
</div> 

...
```

and this works but isn't all that great, so I decided it would be better to do a subgrid for those RelatedDesserts and provide a means of clicking on a row in that grid to display an image in another div - so sort of a master-details-image thing.  Follow?

Right now, I do this by what I feel is a convoluted mechanism and was hoping someone could suggest a better, cleaner way.  Essentially I have substituted this:

```
@Html.Action("SubGrid", RelatedDesserts)
```

for that foreach loop above and that, of course, calls the SubGrid action on the RelatedDesserts controller.  That action does something like this:

```
public PartialViewResult SubGrid(int iceCreamID)
{
   using (var db = new IceCreamEntities())
   {
      return PartialView(iceCreamID);  
   }
}
```

which displays the SubGrid View that looks something like so:

```
<table id="relatedGrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
</table>
<div id="relatedPager" style="text-align: center">
</div>
<div id="relatedImage">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#relatedGrid').jqGrid({
   url: '@Url.Action("GridData", "RelatedDesserts", new {iceCreamID = @Model})',
...
```

and that runs through the related dessert data, creates a result and returns it like so:

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and that fills in the relatedGrid with my data.

But it feels like this isn't all that streamlined and that all the SubGrid piece is doing is providing the target for the results of the GridData action but I'm not sure how to combine those two actions (SubGrid and GridData) to make things simpler.  I may be really going about this the wrong way.  How can I simplify and improve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion: Use one Model, and one View.

Have your Model populated with all the data that you need for the view: make all database calls before you send it to the view.

Then in your View, which we'll call 'Details', you can do all the iterations of HTML (table rows, etc... even multiple iterations - don't worry, that's what Views for!), and setting up of JavaScript. There's no real need to separate these into partial views, unless you see yourself using them on other pages.

There are times when you need to separate things into Partials or Child Actions; like when things are overly complex, or for reusability - But it doesn't seem to be the case here.

In MVC, *simple* makes you smile. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it's a little funky to have those two calls be made. However, by the sounds of it I don't think you could put all the sub-data into the model as @cyrotello suggests. That might be a very beefy model that would be more complicated rather than simpler.

What I would do in this scenario is simply use the link in the master jqGrid to fire off a JavaScript function that would rebind an in-place child jqGrid via a `$.get()` call to a controller action that would serve up the simple model specific to that sub-view. This structure would allow you not only to rebind that in-place jqGrid, but also populate any other supporting elements you might want to have in that child sub-view.

Ultimately, I think the complexity you're sensing is related to trying to *over*-use the MVC framework. It sounds like a simpler JavaScript manipulation of your page might be easier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Josh.  I need to think a bit about what you've written here.  Are you saying that the page that defines my master grid also defines my subgrid and then all the `onSelectRow` call does is call via the JavaScript function my controller action and then the success callback handles providing that data to the grid?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Your main page layout would have both grids, and I'd expect the initial state of the child grid's containing `div` would be `display:none`. Then, you'd have a function bound to the `onSelectRow` event that would make an ajax call to a controller action that would return a ViewModel that you'd use to populate the child information(again  via javascript).